# Total sum of measure

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerpivot

I'm exploring different ways of dealing with a Pareto chart. This time I'm trying to obtain the total sum of a column based on a measure.

The sales table that I have:

| Article | Total |
| --- | --- |
| Article_4 | 1000.00 |
| Article_8 | 412.00 |
| Article_1 | 315.47 |
| Article_3 | 259.10 |

I'm using a measure to compute the % of the cumulated total:

```
Pareto_Chart_CA = 
VAR CostVar = [Total_Cost]
VAR All_CA = CALCULATE([Total_Cost];ALLSELECTED(Sales))

RETURN
DIVIDE(
SUMX(
    FILTER(
            SUMMARIZE(ALLSELECTED(Sales);Sales[Article];
                "Cumm Total"; [Total_Cost]);
                    [Cumm_Total] >= CostVar);
                        [Cumm_Total]);
    All_CA;0)
```

If I add this last measure to the visual table:

| Article | Total | Cumm Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Article_4 | 1000.00 | 0.50 |
| Article_8 | 412.00 | 0.71 |
| Article_1 | 315.47 | 0.87 |
| Article_3 | 259.10 | 1.00 |

Now I would like to only count the number of articles (lines) that have a 'Cumm Total' <= 0.8 so I create another measure as follows:

```
Check_NB_80 = 
    IF(
        Sales[Pareto_Chart_CA] <= 0.8;
        "1";
        "0"
    )
```

The results table:

| Article | Total | Cumm Total | Check_NB_80 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Article_4 | 1000.00 | 0.50 | 1 |
| Article_8 | 412.00 | 0.71 | 1 |
| Article_1 | 315.47 | 0.87 | 0 |
| Article_3 | 259.10 | 1.00 | 0 |

I would calculate the sum of the column 'Check_NB_80' (total of 2) and to put it into a card item to display the number of articles that are <= 80% of the total sales.

Is it possible to do such operation ?

Comment: Why are you returning strings ("0", "1") instead of numerics (0, 1) in your definition for *Check_NB_80*? I would change them to numerics, then you could define a further measure such as `=SUMX(Sales,[Check_NB_80])` to get your desired total.

Answer (score 1):

another option:

1. add index column in PowerQery under "add column" → "index column" → "from 1";
2. calculate comulated sales:

> total_cost = sum([total])
>
> cumm total =
> calculate([total_cost],filter('sales','sales'[Index]<=earlier('sales'[index])))/calculate([total_cost],all('sales'))
>
> Check_NB_80 = IF(sales[cumm total] <= 0.8,1,0)

*note: [total_cost] is measure, [cumm total]&[check_nb_80] is column*

3. use card/other visuals to show

[image]

[image]

but a little confused with your analysis method as Pareto chart always start from smallest to largest which means we calculate [cumm total] based on [total] column sorted from 259 to 1000.

so table and chart would be like that:

[image]

[image]

let me know any confusions.